# Save values in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am trying to read and write data from the my local folder, but my data's not identical.

```
val data =sc.textFile("/user/cts367689/datagen.txt")

 val a=data.map(line=>(line.split(",")(0).toInt+line.split(",")(4).toInt,line.split(",")(3),line.split(",")(2)))

a.saveAsTextFile("/user/cts367689/sparkoutput")
```

**Output:**

```
(526,female,avil)
(635,male,avil)  
(983,male,paracetamol)    
(342,female,paracetamol)    
(158,female,avil)
```

how can i save output as below,need to remove brackets.

**Expected Result:**

```
526,female,avil
635,male,avil    
983,male,paracetamol   
342,female,paracetamol    
158,female,avil
```

Comment: You are saving a RDD of tuple objects to a file, so yes, you get brackets. Have you tried to create a dataframe and save that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val a = data.map (
  line => 
    (line.split(",")(0).toInt + line.split(",")(4).toInt) + "," +
    line.split(",")(3) + "," + 
    line.split(",")(2)
)
```

Try doing this instead of returning it in `()`. That makes a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

spark has capability of handling unstructured files. you are using one those functions.

for CSV(comma separated values) file there are some good libraries to do the same. 
you can have look at this [link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/)

for your question , answer is as shown below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("header", "false")
    .load("/user/cts367689/datagen.txt");

df.select("id", "gender", "name").write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("/user/cts367689/sparkoutput");
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
val a = data.map(line => line.split(",")(0).toInt+line.split(",")(4).toInt+","+line.split(",")(3)+","+line.split(",")(2))
```